# ID cannot represent a non-string and non-integer value

Tags: reactjs, graphql, apollo, strapi, scalar

Here is the thing, I'm building a simple inventory app that has products and parts. Products can have many parts and part can be in many Products.

I'm using React and GraphQL with Strapi backend and I want to update a product to add or remove certain products.

I can't go pass this error in GraphQL playground:

**ID cannot represent a non-string and non-integer value:**

I've tried with id: 1, id: "1", id: `1`, id: `"1"` nothing works. Here is the Docs for the input:

[image]

I'm trying like this but it doesn't work:

```
mutation {
  updateProduct (input:{
    where:{
      id: 2
    }
    data: {
      parts: [
        {
          id: 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }){
    product{
      id
      productName
      parts {
        id
        partName
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'd appreciate any help,

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured it out, turns out docs said it all along. It said:
`parts[ID]`
so I only had to:

```
mutation {
  updateProduct (input:{
    where:{
      id: 2
    }
    data: {
      parts: [
        3
      ]
    }
...
```

or if I wanted multiple parts I had to add it:

```
...
    data: {
      parts: [
         3,2
      ]
    }
...
```